# Error Trying to Dual Boot Ubuntu 15.04 on Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, 15.04

My laptop was originally Windows 7, I upgraded to Windows 10, and then wipe reset it because my previous install of Ubuntu was acting up.  Now when i try to reinstall, it still thinks i have windows 7 installed, because its only detecting my boot partition, and my actual partition is "unknown".  Also, when i try to access the OS Drive without root, it says denied, but when i try to access it with root it disappears completely. [Pictures.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY5La.jpg)

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe try re-burning the LiveUSB/CD or re-downloading the ISO itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply try the install alongside windows 7. Since you upgraded from that, I would think that the fact that the Ubuntu installer shows 7 rather than 10 is probably not a cause for concern.

Also since your installing a release of Ubuntu that came out in april, it's not surprising that it doesn't recognize Windows 10 which launched globally on 29 July - several months later.